# How do you log the data flowing into a SwiftUI view?

Tags: swiftui

Say I'm writing a new View that accepts a couple of pieces of data as arguments with which it builds its contents, what's the best way of getting a log of what data is flowing into the View?

When developing in JS, I can just write console.log(arguments), is there an equivalent in SwiftUI, and if so, where do I place the log call in my View so it won't throw an error?

Comment: You can do a `print()` statement. I would place this in the `.onAppear` function of the view.

Answer (score 1):

James's answer got me partway there - print() is indeed the equivalent of console.log(). The other bit of knowledge I needed was to right-click the play button in the preview window of XCode and turn on 'Debug Preview'.